# The most efficient way for intersection between two very large file in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two huge files a (30 million lines) and b (600 thousand lines). The files look like this:
a:

```
chr1 1234 1235 0.90  
chr1 1376 1375 0.90  
chr1 4556 4547 0.90  
chr3 1110 1111 0.90  
chr4 1234 1235 0.90
```

b:

```
chr1 1     20000 geneA  
chr1 130   18000 geneB  
chr1 25000 32000 geneC  
chr3 1123  3405  geneD  
chr4 14    1835  geneF
```

Now I want to search each line of file a columns 1,2 and match them with each line of file b columns 1,2,3 and if the values in clum 2 of file a is in between of values in columns 2 and 3 of file b then print that line with corresponding line from file b.
I wrote the following code to take advantage of the dictionary python. This code store file a to dictionary and then loops over the range of (columns 2,columns 3) in each line of file b and matches it to dictionary. This works but it is super slow as my files are huge.
Does anyone know a better way to do that?
Thanks,
Vahid.

```
a_dict= dict()                  
with open(a) as file1:
    for line in file1:
        line= line.rstrip().split('\t')
        key= line[0]+'_'+line[1]
        a_dict[key]= line[3]



with open(b) as file2:
    for line in file2:
        line=line.rstrip().split('\t')
        for i in range(int(line[1]), int(line[2])):
            key= line[0]+'_'+str(i)
            try:
                common= a_dict[key]
                print('\t'.join(key.split('_')),str(common), '\t'.join(line), sep='\t')
            except:
                continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and trying different approaches I came with this solution which is super efficient and does the job in several minutes:
First I indexed my file first file (file a) using tabix:
This part in bash:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n a | bgzip > a.bed.bgz
tabix a.bed.bgz
```

And then using tabix in python I extract regions in the first file with matched column 1 with second file and values in columns 2 and 3 that are in between of values in columns 2 and 3 of the second file.
This part in python:

```
import tabix
tb = tabix.open(a.bed.bgz)
with open(b) as b:
    for line in b:
        line=line.rstrip()
        chrom= line.split()[0]
        start= int(line.split()[1])
        end= int(line.split()[2])
        try:
            records = tb.query(chrom, start, end)
            for record in records:
                print('\t'.join(record),line, sep='\t')
        except:
            continue
```